# Android UX - how to show the user that a list item is clickable?

Tags: android, user-experience

I have a list of things in an Android activity.

Do I need to add something to let the user know that they will get more detail by clicking an item?  (It opens a new activity.)

I could add a button to every item, but it looks ugly.

Comment: I guess you don't, anyhow user will gonna touch your listitem sometime. I doesn't see any need for such indication.

Comment: maybe using showcasing like [MaterialIntroView](https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView?) does?

Comment: Agrees to both the above comments.!

Comment: ShowcaseView library is the best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Showcaseview will be the best way

2) or use Card view , this way the user will know for sure that the item is clickable and also in some cases, expandable.
(Similar to Call logs in Google Phones)

Answer (score 2):

There are **3 ways** that currently cross my mind:

1. **Using Simple Pop Up Message**.
   This could be achieved by using a dialog (this could distract users, not recommended) or using [SnackBar](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing.html).
   *cons:* user have a great chance to be distracted from our original intention.
2. **Using ToolTip**
   Tooltip is often used in desktop application. it almost like using a button though we use it as a mere information.
   Some library of `ToolTip`:
   [android-simple-tooltip](https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip)
   [tooltips](https://github.com/tomergoldst/tooltips)
   [tooltip](https://github.com/jayrambhia/Tooltip)
   *cons:* For a ListView or RecyclerView we could end using too much Tooltip.
3. **Using ShowCaseView**
   From UI and UX perspective, this is the way to go. Google use it when first time user of Android open up his device.
   Some library of ShowCaseView:
   [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)
   [MaterialIntroView](https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView)
   [Android-Cling](https://github.com/MajeurAndroid/Android-Cling)

Answer (score 1):

You need not to do that. Default behaviour as in UX goes like something shall come up on click of a list item.

You can either open a new activity on click of item where detailed description can be shown with options in menu.

Or you can open up an AlertDialog with items to show user options when he clicks on list item.

```
String[] items = {"View", "Delete", "Update"};
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // choices goes here
    }

});
builder.create().show();
```